# Why is this SQL syntax throwing an error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting an error when executing this statement in a longer script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
           WHERE name = N'uncertainty_requested' 
             AND object_id = object_id(N'workorder'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'workorder.uncertainty_requested exists';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE workorder
        ADD uncertainty_requested CHAR(1);

    UPDATE workorder
    SET uncertainty_requested = 'F';

    PRINT 'workorder.uncertainty_requested added.'
END 
GO
```

The error message is:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'uncertainty_requested'.

Using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is compiled before it is executed, and the missing column is a compile-time error.  You can handle this using dynamic SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE workorder
    ADD uncertainty_requested CHAR(1);
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE workorder SET uncertainty_requested = ''F''';
PRINT 'workorder.uncertainty_requested added.'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for both the solution and the education!  I did have to add an N in front of the SQL to get it to work...
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE workorder SET uncertainty_requested = ''F''';